A confusion with logic level output description
Following shows the difference between TTL and 5V-CMOS logic:

If a device manual states it has TTL input I can say that one can expect 3V pulse can work as input.
But my confusion is, what does it mean if the trigger output of a device is stated as TTL. In that case does that mean the device trigger output voltage is unknown(between 2.4 to 5V)?

Are you confused with the meaning of Vt in the above diagram?


what does it mean if the trigger output of a device is stated as TTL.

It means that a high output is guaranteed to be at least 2.4 V when delivering its specified output current. It may be higher, but you should not expect it to be near to 5 V. In particular, you should not expect it to drive ordinary CMOS directly, which requires a minimum of 3.5 V for a high to be recognised unambiguously. That's what HCT/ACT CMOS families are for, to be driven properly by TTL level outputs.
It might mean that the output is driven by a real TTL buffer IC, or it might simply mean that the output voltages are TTL compatible.

In that case does that mean the device trigger output voltage is unknown(between 2.4 to 5V)?

It will be somewhere in that range, yes. You might expect 3 to 3.5 V typically, but it's not guaranteed. When used with an external pullup resistor, a TTL gate will deliver a higher voltage 'high' out. People often use 3.3 V CMOS outputs and call them 'TTL compatible'.
Now why would a manufacturer describe their output as TTL, rather than measuring and specifying a voltage level? Perhaps they actually use a TTL buffer as their output device. Calling their output 'TTL' tells you all you need to know to be able to work with it. It will work OK with a TTL input, and an HCT or ACT input. It may not work with an HC or AC input, though it might sometimes1. If you use a comparator to detect the level coming out of it, then its threshold should be set to somewhere between 0.8 V and 2 V, ideally around 1.5 V.
For the manufacturer to specify a voltage level, he has got to specify the min and max it will never exceed, tested into some kind of load. That's extra work for no benefit, given that all of that testing and specifying work has already been done by the TTL manufacturers.
1 In the worst case, it will work flawlessly with an HC or AC input while you are designing, developing and testing your equipment, and then stop working when it gets to the customer. Don't work to typicals and the measured results of samples, work to min and max specifications in the data sheets.

The thing mostly confuses me: The trigger output is stated as TTL instead of writing the voltage level. They could measure it and write something more specific. Since they write output as TTL, does that mean the output is dependent on load? I really dont get why they didnt just messure the trigger ouput voltage and just stated as TTL. Could you also comnent on this.

When we read the trigger out output is stated as TTL does it also mean the logic gates literally made up of BJTs?

@cm64 made of BJTs? Absolutely not. It's TTL signal levels. It might be a TTL gate, but it might be vacuum tubes for all you know, or need to know.

(work to [spec's] especially when not testing "extreme" supply voltages &temperatures)

@Neil_UK But in many pages I see such statements: "The Transistor-Transistor Logic (TTL) is a logic family made up of BJTs (bipolar junction transistors)."  https://www.elprocus.com/transistor-transistor-logic-ttl/#:~:text=The%20Transistor%2DTransistor%20Logic%20(TTL,Gate%20%26%20the%207400%20NAND%20gate. This is a bit confusing.

@cm64 TTL logic (the ICs, the hardware) is built with BJTs. TTL logic levels are voltages at specified currents, and can be provided by anything that can provide a suitable voltage, for instance a 3.3 V CMOS output. Does your device say it has a TTL output device, or it provides a TTL signal, or provides TTL compatible levels, or something else? As long as you interpret the output it gives according to the TTL specification of 0 to 0.8 V low, 2 V and above as high, then you will be OK. You don't need to know what is inside the box generating the output.

Oh I see so you mean TTL levels can be implemented by anything even with CMOS? So there's difference between being "TTL output"(can use any logic family) and "TTL logic gate"(uses BJT). Did I get you correct?

@cm64 Yes, you have it, TTL logic levels can be generated in many different ways. The spec on them is very broad, so it's not difficult to implement and stay within the spec. It doesn't matter whether you use 3.3V cmos, a physical TTL buffer, or a 200 ohm resistor to ground with a switchable 15 mA current source into it (as I actually used a few decades ago for a very specific high speed application).
